# Implementing Union-Find Algorithm for Kruskal's Algorithm to find Minimum Spanning Tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to solve the following Leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/connecting-cities-with-minimum-cost), and my approach is to figure out the total weight of the minimum spanning tree (MST) from the input graph using Kruskal's Algorithm using the Union-Find data structure. However, my code online passes 51/63 of the test cases, returning the incorrect result on the following test case, which is too hard to debug, since the input graph is too large.

```
50
[[2,1,22135],[3,1,13746],[4,3,37060],[5,2,48513],[6,3,49607],[7,1,97197],[8,2,95909],[9,2,82668],[10,2,48372],[11,4,17775],[12,2,6017],[13,1,51409],[14,2,12884],[15,7,98902],[16,14,52361],[17,8,11588],[18,12,86814],[19,17,49581],[20,4,41808],[21,11,77039],[22,10,80279],[23,16,61659],[24,12,89390],[25,24,10042],[26,12,78278],[27,15,30756],[28,6,2883],[29,8,3478],[30,7,29321],[31,12,47542],[32,20,35806],[33,3,26531],[34,12,16321],[35,27,82484],[36,7,55920],[37,24,21253],[38,23,90537],[39,7,83795],[40,36,70353],[41,34,76983],[42,14,63416],[43,15,39590],[44,9,86794],[45,3,31968],[46,19,32695],[47,17,40287],[48,1,27993],[49,12,86349],[50,11,52080],[17,27,65829],[42,45,87517],[14,23,96130],[5,50,3601],[10,17,2017],[26,44,4118],[26,29,93146],[1,9,56934],[22,43,5984],[3,22,13404],[13,28,66475],[11,14,93296],[16,44,71637],[7,37,88398],[7,29,56056],[2,34,79170],[40,44,55496],[35,46,14494],[32,34,25143],[28,36,59961],[10,49,58317],[8,38,33783],[8,28,19762],[34,41,69590],[27,37,26831],[15,23,53060],[5,11,7570],[20,42,98814],[18,34,96014],[13,43,94702],[1,46,18873],[44,45,43666],[22,40,69729],[4,25,28548],[8,46,19305],[15,22,39749],[33,48,43826],[14,15,38867],[13,22,56073],[3,46,51377],[13,15,73530],[6,36,67511],[27,38,76774],[6,21,21673],[28,49,72219],[40,50,9568],[31,37,66173],[14,29,93641],[4,40,87301],[18,46,41318],[2,8,25717],[1,7,3006],[9,22,85003],[14,45,33961],[18,28,56248],[1,31,10007],[3,24,23971],[6,28,24448],[35,39,87474],[10,50,3371],[7,18,26351],[19,41,86238],[3,8,73207],[11,34,75438],[3,47,35394],[27,32,69991],[6,40,87955],[2,18,85693],[5,37,50456],[8,20,59182],[16,38,58363],[9,39,58494],[39,43,73017],[10,15,88526],[16,23,48361],[4,28,59995],[2,3,66426],[6,17,29387],[15,38,80738],[12,43,63014],[9,11,90635],[12,20,36051],[13,25,1515],[32,40,72665],[10,40,85644],[13,40,70642],[12,24,88771],[14,46,79583],[30,49,45432],[21,34,95097],[25,48,96934],[2,35,79611],[9,26,71147],[11,37,57109],[35,36,67266],[42,43,15913],[3,30,44704],[4,32,46266],[5,10,94508],[31,39,45742],[12,25,56618],[10,45,79396],[15,28,78005],[19,32,94010],[36,46,4417],[6,35,7762],[10,13,12161],[49,50,60013],[20,23,6891],[9,50,63893],[35,43,74832],[10,24,3562],[6,8,47831],[29,32,82689],[7,47,71961],[14,41,82402],[20,33,38732],[16,26,24131],[17,34,96267],[21,46,81067],[19,47,41426],[13,24,68768],[1,25,78243],[2,27,77645],[11,25,96335],[31,45,30726],[43,44,34801],[3,42,22953],[12,23,34898],[37,43,32324],[18,44,18539],[8,13,59737],[28,37,67994],[13,14,25013],[22,41,25671],[1,6,57657],[8,11,83932],[42,48,24122],[4,15,851],[9,29,70508],[7,32,53629],[3,4,34945],[2,32,64478],[7,30,75022],[14,19,55721],[20,22,84838],[22,25,6103],[8,49,11497],[11,32,22278],[35,44,56616],[12,49,18681],[18,43,56358],[24,43,13360],[24,47,59846],[28,43,36311],[17,25,63309],[1,14,30207],[39,48,22241],[13,26,94146],[4,33,62994],[40,48,32450],[8,19,8063],[20,29,56772],[10,27,21224],[24,30,40328],[44,46,48426],[22,45,39752],[6,43,96892],[2,30,73566],[26,36,43360],[34,36,51956],[18,20,5710],[7,22,72496],[3,39,9207],[15,30,39474],[11,35,82661],[12,50,84860],[14,26,25992],[16,39,33166],[25,41,11721],[19,40,68623],[27,28,98119],[19,43,3644],[8,16,84611],[33,42,52972],[29,36,60307],[9,36,44224],[9,48,89857],[25,26,21705],[29,33,12562],[5,34,32209],[9,16,26285],[22,37,80956],[18,35,51968],[37,49,36399],[18,42,37774],[1,30,24687],[23,43,55470],[6,47,69677],[21,39,6826],[15,24,38561]]
```

I'm having trouble understanding why my code will fail a test case, since I believe I am implementing the steps of Kruskal's Algorithm propertly:

1. Sorting the connections in increasing order of weight.
2. Building the MST by going through each connection in the sorted list and selecting that connection if it does not result in a cycle in the MST.

Below is my Java code:

```
class UnionFind {
    // parents[i] = parent node of node i.
    // If a node is the root node of a component, we define its parent
    // to be itself.
    int[] parents;
    
    public UnionFind(int n) {
        this.parents = new int[n];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            this.parents[i] = i;
        }
    }
    
    // Merges two nodes into the same component.
    public void union(int node1, int node2) {
        int node1Component = find(node1);
        int node2Component = find(node2);
        
        this.parents[node1Component] = node2Component;
    }
    
    // Returns the component that a node is in.
    public int find(int node) {
        while (this.parents[node] != node) {
            node = this.parents[node];
        }
        
        return node;
    }
}

class Solution {
    public int minimumCost(int n, int[][] connections) {
        UnionFind uf = new UnionFind(n + 1);
        
        // Sort edges by increasing cost.
        Arrays.sort(connections, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final int[] a1, final int[] a2) {
                return a1[2] - a2[2];
            }
        });
        
        int edgeCount = 0;
        int connectionIndex = 0;
        int weight = 0;
        
        // Greedy algorithm: Choose the edge with the smallest weight 
        // which does not form a cycle. We know that an edge between 
        // two nodes will result in a cycle if those nodes are already 
        // in the same component.
        for (int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
            int[] connection = connections[i];
            int nodeAComponent = uf.find(connection[0]);
            int nodeBComponent = uf.find(connection[1]);
            
            if (nodeAComponent != nodeBComponent) {
                weight += connection[2];
                edgeCount++;
            }
            
            if (edgeCount == n - 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // MST, by definition, must have (n - 1) edges.
        if (edgeCount == n - 1) {
            return weight;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the full problem's text. This problem is locked for premium access

Comment: In your code, you're not uniting sets after `weight += connection[2]; edgeCount++;`. I think this might be the case

Comment: 2 problems: 1) `union` is never called.  2) your comparator returns the wrong result when `a1[2] - a2[2]`  overflows.

Answer (score 0):

As @geobreze stated, I forgot to unite the components (disjoint sets) of node A and node B. Below is the corrected code:

```
if (nodeAComponent != nodeBComponent) {
    uf.union(nodeAComponent, nodeBComponent);
    weight += connection[2];
    edgeCount++;
}
```